# SharePoint 2013: Group Search Results by Site Name

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, display-template, sharepoint-ootb

I have added a Search box and a Search Results web part with the query which retrieves documents from different subsites.

Now, what I want is to group this documents by using Site Name and show the documents below corresponding site label like below:

**Site 1**:

1. Document 1
2. Document 2

**Site 2**:

1. Document 1
2. Document 2

and so on.

OOTB solution will be preferred(not necessary that solution should be OOTB only).

Any help will be much apperciated.

Comment: Does anyone know solution to this question?